# Java display unicode code points instead of string literal

Tags: java, intellij-idea, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

Suppose I have a `String s = "green"`. What should I do to get its Unicode representation `"\u0067\u0072\u0065\u0065\u006E"`?

Comment: @Mads T, https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter. I was wondering if there is some java method or built in intellij functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is any method which will provide this functionality, however if you were to build a custom method, then you can do something like this:

```
private static String toUnicodeString(String str) {
    String ret = "";
    for (char ch: str.toCharArray())
        ret += String.format("\\u%04x", (int) ch);
    return ret;
}
```

and so `toUnicodeString("green")` returns `\u0067\u0072\u0065\u0065\u006e`